# Change background of <td> without adding class to <td>

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Background**

I am trying to show a list of scheduled events for a user, to do this I am showing a bootstrap table with two columns, one is a generated list of 15m time intervals and the other is the event itself.

Scheduled events have a green background.

**Problem**

Due to the way I have setup my table and foreach loop I can't add a class to the `<td>` tag to change the background color depending on if there is an event or not.

**What I have tried so far**

Here is my view to display the data, I have added a div with a class 'event' which has a green background to denote that the event is scheduled.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Event</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- shows times as 1472792400 => 6:00, 6:15, 6:30 -->
        <?php foreach ($intervals as $seconds => $interval) : ?>
            <tr>

                <td class="col-md-1">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                        <?php echo $interval; ?>
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td class="col-md-10">
                    <?php foreach ($events as $key => $event) : ?>
                            <?php if ($event->seconds_start == $seconds) : ?>
                                <div class="event-header">
                                    <span class="label label-default"><?php echo $event->event; ?></span>
                                </div>
                            <?php elseif ($event->seconds_start < $seconds && $event->seconds_end >= $seconds + 900) : ?>
                                <div class="event">&nbsp;</div>
                            <?php else : ?>
                                <!-- nothing -->
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </td>
                <td class="col-md-1"></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my events table

[image]

and my css file

```
.event-header {
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:600;
    background: #75a575;
    border-bottom:1px solid #75a575 !important;
    margin: -8px -10px -10px;
}

.event {
    background: #abdbab;
    margin: -8px -10px -10px;
}
```

here is how the events page looks so far

[image]

**question**

So basically if the event time equals the displayed time then I want to change the entire background color of the `<td>` to show that there is an event scheduled... **but I can't add a class to the `<td>` because my logic block is within the `<td></td>` already**. How do I do this?

**UPDATE 1**

Adding the `<td>` tags within the if statement (the ideal solution) like this...

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Time</th>
            <th>Event</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($intervals as $seconds => $interval) : ?>
            <tr>

                <td class="col-md-1">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                        <?php echo $interval; ?>
                    </div>
                </td>

                <?php foreach ($events as $key => $event) : ?>
                        <?php if ($event->seconds_start == $seconds) : ?>
                            <td class="col-md-10 event-header">
                                <span class="label label-default"><?php echo $event->event; ?></span>
                            </td>
                        <?php elseif ($event->seconds_start < $seconds && $event->seconds_end >= $seconds + 900) : ?>
                            <td class="col-md-10 event"><td>
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <td class="col-md-10"><td>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>

                <td class="col-md-1"></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Produces the following view:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Getting closer, by showing nothing in the else statement, however the layout is still very broken and I am having a hard time processing where I am going wrong...

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Time</th>
            <th>Event</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($intervals as $seconds => $interval) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="col-md-1">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                        <?php echo $interval; ?>
                    </div>
                </td>

                <?php foreach ($events as $key => $event) : ?>
                    <?php if ($event->seconds_start == $seconds) : ?>
                        <td class="col-md-10 event-header">
                            <span class="label label-default"><?php echo $event->event; ?></span>
                        </td>
                    <?php elseif ($event->seconds_start < $seconds && $event->seconds_end >= $seconds + 900) : ?>
                        <td class="col-md-10 event">hello<td>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <!-- nothing -->
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

now shows...

[image]

as you can see, whene there is not event matching the time then no column is shown, however if I add the column in the else statement and even add a break the layout goes haywire...

Comment: Why can't you just style it?

Comment: Style what?....

Comment: The <td> .... <td style='background-color: xxx;'   class=' .......' > etc

Comment: I only want the bg color to show if the event start equals the displayed time, so whether I use a class or inline-style is irrelivant, I can only check if that condition is met within the td tag.

Comment: Since parent selectors aren't a thing in CSS (yet?), you could quickly achieve this by inserting an empty element, positioned absolutely and filling the `<td>` with the desired background colour. Not the greatest approach, but given the constraints I suppose that's the easiest option.

Comment: That is an idea, shame about the parent selector thing... trying now.

Comment: Why can't you ..  if (the event start equals the displayed time) {<td display with back color} else {<td display without}

Comment: RGriffiths that is a very good point, which I have struggled with for a couple of days now... when I implement your suggestion then if I add more then one event each sequential event gets added to a different colum breaking the layout completely, I will update my question to show you what I mean.

Comment: OP has been updated

Comment: That is what is bugging me, if you look in the last screenshot there is a phantom little <td></td> showing and I cant work out why... hmm

Comment: Why do you have else nothing? In you first example you have <td class="col-md-10"><td>. I am not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve. Do your classes include widths? What do you actually want it to look like?

Comment: RGriffiths, and others, I truely have to apologise, it appears the problems were caused by me failing to close a <td> tag and of this I am truely embarassed, in the future I will try to show more respect for the communities time, I am trying to get stuff done in an extremely distracting environment... and I guess that is the price I pay, again, major apologies... @RGriffiths I will accept any answer you give and thanks for your patience.

Comment: Only just spotted that myseld. Easily done. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: Do not think this question is related to codeigniter. It's more to do with css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification exists but it looks browsers doesn’t support it yet.

https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject

The proposed code would be something like this:

```
!td .event-header { /* styles */ }
```

The only solution I see is to fall back to JavaScript. It could be worse than to refactor PHP thought.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the style of a DOM node, you **HAVE** to apply CSS rules to it. You can't get around that. If you don't want `<td class="...">` to do that, then you'll have to do `<td style="...">` instead. One way or another, you'll HAVE to write CSS for this to happen.